# GC overhead limit exceeded- Out of memory in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I tried running my Splink library to get data linking and deduplication between different datasource which has millions of record but unfortunaley am getting either out of memory error or Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. I have attached my cluster configuration screenshot as well. Could anyone please help me out to resolve this issue.
[cluster configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB29p.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6doc.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgFPp.png)

Comment: are you using any joins or collect operations  within the scripts?

Comment: Yes, am using joins.

Comment: Are you using broadcast join?

Answer (score 2):

GC errors and RPC connection error happen for two reason.

Some executor is using too much memory and crash (Or crash for some other reason like network failure) and the driver can´t retrieve it´s information ou receive a response.

You have too many RDDs stored at your Heap space (Spark split this memory for RDDs and GC, when too many RDDs are kept in memory, Garbace Collector may be affected and even stop working)

Try acessing the information about the executors and check how many memnory is beeing used by those RDDs. Probably more than it should use.

To Fix this problem you can:

- try to use checkpoint to force spark to evaluate the expressions and avoid to concentrate all the transformations to a single point.
- Use df.unpersist() to force RDDs to be set as "Remove from memory" after you use.
- Cache some dataframe, if joins operations are applied to it and used multiple times (Only apply if all conditions are true). Don't forget to unpersist after using it.
- Use broadcast joins if one of the dataframes used in joins are small enought to be copied in multiples nodes. This avoid Shuffle and save memory.
- Do note keep every data in memory, it is limited, so maybe saving temporary data as WORM files may boost your memory use.